# PayPal iOS SDK Sample App

Tags: ios, paypal

I'm having a play with the PayPal iOS SDK App which I downloaded from https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK an it works beautifully in sandbox mode BUT I cannot find any property to set for the merchant email address. This is mind boggling to me, as the 'money' has to be sent to the merchant. So the question is, how is this even working?

I'm sure I'm overlooking something. Excuse the stupid question so bear with me.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Using the iOS SDK, the place for this information is in the `PayPalConfiguration` object -- it is passed as a parameter for all the PayPal provided view controllers.

So for example, in the PayPal demo app:

```
// Xcode 8.1, Swift 3.0

//MainViewController
//yadda yadda...
var payPalConfig = PayPalConfiguration()
// etc. etc.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Some other stuff

    // Set up payPalConfig
    payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = false
    payPalConfig.merchantName = "Awesome Shirts, Inc."
    payPalConfig.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = URL(string: "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full")
    payPalConfig.merchantUserAgreementURL = URL(string: "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full")

    // blah blah blah
}
```

This config object is later passed in as:

```
PayPalPaymentViewController(payment: payment, configuration: payPalConfig, delegate: self)
```

---

**EDIT: Correction** - you're right, there is no property for the merchant's email address, even in the `PayPalConfiguration` object, just the merchant's name, and merchant's privacy/EULA urls.

However, it should not boggle the mind, as it were, since the merchant has a PayPal [Merchant/Business] account which will receive the money (and they certainly have the merchant's email address), and the merchant needn't expose an email address. The receiver, on the other hand, might not have a PayPal account (yet), so there are properties for the receiver's email address -- e.g., the `defaultUserEmail` in the configuration object, or the `payeeEmail` property of the `PayPalPayment` object ([docs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/PayPal-iOS-SDK/2.16.1/Classes/PayPalPayment.html#//api/name/payeeEmail)).

Answer (score -1):

In IOS SDK, you need to update two files to reflect the environment and merchant client id.

**A.**  `ZZAppDelegate.m` File

```
 [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION",PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_SANDBOX"}];
```

**B.**  `ZZMainViewController.m` File

define kPayPalEnvironment `PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork`

In IOS SDK, you don't need to input merchant's email address, you need to apply one client id in REST APP:https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications, then place this clent id in above file.